# How to enable mysqli error reporting via INI settings?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mysqli

This will be a rather short question but I have not been able to locate a way to set the following within my `.htaccess` file

Im looking for the `.htaccess` equivalent of:

`mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`

Comment: There is no way to call a PHP code in the Apache web-server's configuration file.

Comment: @YourCommonSense thank you for the response, I was assuming/hoping there would be an `ini` or `htaccess` setting for this control.

Comment: You should look at how to configure MySQLi

Comment: There are only so many MySQLi values you can tune in `php.ini` or `.htaccess`. For a complete listing, see `phpinfo()`. As follows: `mysqli.allow_local_infile, mysqli.allow_persistent, mysqli.default_host, mysqli.default_port, mysqli.default_pw, mysqli.default_socket, mysqli.default_user, mysqli.max_links, mysqli.max_persistent, mysqli.reconnect, mysqli.rollback_on_cached_plink`

Answer (score 1):

There is no PHP ini setting for enabling mysqli error reporting. The only way to do it, is via the command you have in the question. This should never be a huge problem, since it is only a single line of code, which must always be put before `new mysqli`. In total the connection code in your whole application should be no more than 3 lines of code in a single place. All that you need is this:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$mysqli = new mysqli(); // values coming from INI file
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8mb4'); // always set the charset
```

Comment: Is it best practice to have the `mysqli` credentials in the `.htaccess` file? I have recently been working more with OOP PHP and have them set as properties in a class.

Comment: @FamousAv8er That is a separate question. Credentials need to be stored in file that is inaccessible from the web.